How do I write unique images to each video frames?
There are unique images for each frame of a video and I am trying to use ffmpeg to overlay the images back to source video to generate same source video metadata with overlayed image.
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 161831150/6650448 -r 161831150/6650448 -i images_%08d.png -filter_complex overlay output.mp4

I don't know if it is because irrational number of frame rates but the output video of this command generated has different video data such as fps, total frames etc.. that adds couple more seconds to source video so the output video is not exactly the same.
What is best way and most efficient way to add unique images to each frame of a video and keep the source video information?
